# Discussion: enumerate tag - list tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

The [enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumerate) tag description says

> {enumerate} is about the enumerate list environment. If you use this
>   tag, add the more general {lists} tag.

Why should we add a more general tag? Giving a more specific tag seems more reasonable to me. Or did I misunderstood the description?

Comment: It may seem redundant, but LaTeX provides the user with a generic `list` environment (in TeX this is a `trivlist`), which gives rise to [tag:lists].

Comment: you may be right, but what if an curious user who searches your Q from top ( [lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists) ) to bottom( [enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumerate) ) instead of narrowly searching Q's in `enumerate` tag, `lists` tag segregate all sub environments, generic tags won't harm IMO.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the case of list environments, questions and answers about one specific type (`enumerate`, `itemize`, ...) will often be useful for other types as well. Examples are Q+A's about spacing or page breaks before or after lists, spacing between list items, indentation of item labels, ... Therefore, the tag descriptions of [enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumerate), [itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itemize), and [description](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/description) recommend to add the general [lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists) tag. If you're sure that a question is only applicable to a specific list type (e.g., cross-referencing items of an `enumerate` list), you may omit the general tag.

Comment: I see. Didn't know that these problems can be useful for other list types as well, but it seems reasonable. Thanks!